# iFrame with 100% of Screen

Tags: html, iframe

I am simply trying to make a iFrame to show a website. The current iframe code that I have does in fact work, but I would like to make the iframe show 100% on the height and width. The current code shows the site 100% height, but not width, so can someone help me with this?

Here is the exact page so you can see what I am talking about:
http://dnatecservices.com/wp-demo/Untitled-2.html

Please view the page source to see my html. For some reason, I am unable to post the code here.

So can someone provide me with an HTML that will show this iframe both 100% on the height and width? I want the site to show on 100% of the user's screen.

Comment: You `#container` has a width of 1000px, so the iframe won't be bigger than that..

Comment: Just curious: Do you want some others content? Or do you want to hide the underlying URL? Man-in-the-middle, or something?

Answer (score 0):

Your css code shows:

```
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 550px;
  position: relative;
}
```

remove the width here and it will show the Iframe with 100% width

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. My issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After you remove the width:1000px; from the 'container' DIV you will want to remove the border from the iframe :

```
#iframe {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
border: 0px;
}
```